# how to select a Ventura wallpaper image on Sonoma?

Tags: ventura, wallpaper

After upgrading to Sonoma and trying several of its wallpapers, how do I go back to one of Ventura's gorgeous ocean photos?

Are those images available to download? The file was present at least until I started viewing Sonoma wallpapers.

Answer (score 0):

I just now found some of the older wallpaper images like "Catalina Shoreline." They're rather hidden under System Settings > Wallpaper:

1. Select the screen you want to change in the pop-up menu near the top.
2. Scroll down past Dynamic Wallpapers, Landscape, Cityscape, Underwater, Earth, & Shuffle Aerials to **Pictures**.
3. Scroll horizontally past 7 "Hello Metallic" pictures, Pro Black, and 10 synthetic neon pictures to get to 16 beautiful, relaxing **Big Sur** and **Catalina** landscape photos.
4. Breathe in.
5. Breathe out.